# AsseticBundle: Should the content of asset files affect the auto-generated asset filename?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I use AsseticBundle in a Symfony 2.1 project, and adding new code to existing js and css files do not generate a new asset filename.

I know that there is another solution to it, using assets_version, but it would make sense that by modifying the asset files should also have an impact on the generated filename.

Do you have any idea why the asset files are served using the same filename no matter what changes are done?

Comment: Do you set the name explicitly (as far as I remember `output="foo"` or something like that)? In my case I get a new filename everytime I deploy (means: dump assets)

Comment: No, I don't have a `output="foo"`. And if I deploy again it does not change anything. But my modifications in the code are included in the new generated asset files.